# On commutant of $II_{1}$ factors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $M$ is $II_{1}$ factor but need not be in standard form. Under what condition (on $M$ or Hilbert space) is the commutant $M'$ of $M$ again $II_{1}$ factor on the Hilbert space acted by $M$?

Comment: Exactly when the Hilbert space has finite von Neumann dimension over $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at V. Jones 2015 von Neumann notes
https://math.vanderbilt.edu/jonesvf/VONNEUMANNALGEBRAS2015/VonNeumann2015.pdf

Theorem 10.2.1(1).

You shall learn the coupling constant first.

Comment: how to show that coupling constant is finite if you don't know the exact size of trace, the only you know the existence!!

Comment: Do you mean the "Hilbert space acted by M" is $L^2(M)$, where the coupling constant is 1? In this case $M'\subset B(L^2(M))$ is a type $\text{II}_1$ factor.

Comment: No not in $L^{2}(M)$? need not be in standrad form